# Wing Shape: Long/Wide Span Wings vs Deep Wings

Tags: aerodynamics, wing

Planes use wings to generate lift. The wider the span of the wing (looking at the plane from the front) the more lift it generates, however, this is at the expense of more drag.

Some planes like the F-22, or hang gliders, however, seem to adopt the strategy of having their wings larger front to back, instead of extending more out to the side. I'd guess that having a deeper wing would also increase lift at the expense drag and weight.

A third way to increase lift at the expense of drag is to increase the angle of attack of the wing, but I am not really interested in that for this question.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of a deeper wing versus a wider wing span?

Comment: @fooot thanks, I was not aware of the term aspect ratio

Comment: Of course! Welcome to Aviation.SE!